# Nil-potency and similarity between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, nilpotence

> If $A$ and $B$ are similar $n\times n$ matrices, then it follows that
>   $B$ is nil-potent if and only if $A$ is nil-potent.

I am not allowed to use Jordan blocks

My attempt is to proof something else but the above lemma follows directly from it.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $D$ is a basis for some vector-space $V$, if I can show that $T:V\to V$ is nilpotent if and only if $[T]_D$ (matrix representation with respect to basis $D$) is also nilpotent with identical nilpotency index $k$

Let $u\in V, u\ne0$.

Then it follows that

$T(u)=[T]_Du\ne0$

$T^2(u)=[T]_D^2u\ne0$,

...,

$T^k(u)=[T]_D^k u=0$

It follows that $[T]_D$ is nilpotent of degree $k$.

The other way around:

Let $[T]_D$ be a nil-potent matrix of degree $k$ such that $T(u)=[T]_Du$

Then it follows that $T^k(u)=[T]_d^ku=0$

Have I missed anything? are the notations correctly used?

Comment: $A\sim B \Leftrightarrow \exists T$ such that $A = TBT^{-1}$. If $B^{k}=0$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ show that  $A^k = 0$. Do you see how?

Comment: Yes, I do. since $A^k=TB^kT^{-1}$, it's very intuitive to me that the lemma is true, however I am wondering if my proof is complete; my prof. always says finding different ways to prove things always makes it easier to grasp the concepts and my only problem with this course is the concepts.